# Spring Boot EAR Packaging

Tags: java, spring-boot, ear

Similar to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377533/skinny-wars-with-multiple-spring-boot-wars-into-an-ear-package-and-deploy-to-jbo) I'm trying to package several `WAR` modules into a single `ear`. I have been able to get each running individually as `WARs` and packaged as an EAR. My current issue is in dealing with a shared `context`. Essentially trying to separate `RESTful` API from WS but sharing the underlying service `context`.

Thus far the closest thing I can find close to this is [Spring IO Blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/); I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of something a little more up-to-date as I'm having no luck.

There seem to be a number of ways to accomplish this via `XML` but haven't run across anything more [shared context xml](https://github.com/balabanmario/ear-with-spring-shared-context)

Comment: This exactly the same situation I am considering currently. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did actually; I'll see if I can't dig up that project and pull the details.