# Deploy multiple Spring Boot modules with Maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created two separate maven modules (let's call them `MODULE1` and `MODULE2`) which are submodules of a third integration module (`SUPERMODULE`).

`MODULE1` and `MODULE2` are both Spring Boot Web Applications. What I'm trying to achieve is to start (not build) both projects / web apps by means of `SUPERMODULE`.

As I see it, there are two options:

1. Deploy them both to the same tomcat server (probably the better & more interesting solution)
2. Deploy them to different tomcat servers with different ports

I found no viable example to achieve either one of these options (... by means of a single maven integration project). Hence, I would be glad if someone could point me into the right direction - or are both possibilities bad practice?

Comment: "or are both possibilities bad practice?" It depends. If you're talking about deploying from your local machine\dev environment, then yes. If, alternatively, you're trying to push out with a build server then this can work in several ways. The maven wagon plugin comes to mind immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You said :

> Deploy them both to the same tomcat server

## (1) [Build automation software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software)

Any Build Automation tool (Jenkins, bamboo...) would allow you to create a job that deploys both your wars to tomcat (the same server or different server, you can setup your job as you wish).

Do you use an automation software ? I believe that would be the best the solution / best practices.

## (2) Build an EAR - Deploy to [Tomee](http://tomee.apache.org)

You said:

> What I'm trying to achieve is to start (not build) both projects / web
> apps by means of SUPERMODULE.

What you are really describing is an EAR!

**I'll describe the idea, however, it seems Spring boot does not play well with EAR: [Spring Boot EAR Packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667392/spring-boot-ear-packaging) and https://github.com/purple52/spring-boot-ear-skinny-war**

Since your 2 submodules are spring boot app, you could:

- build the submodules as WAR
- have your Supermodule build an EAR
- include both WARs in the EAR (maven dependencies)
- this *however* implies that you use (for instance) [Tomee](http://tomee.apache.org) instead of tomcat (is that an option for you?).
- **as mentioned above, after some research it seems a spring-boot war does not work when packaged inside an EAR. The `SpringServletContainerInitializer` isn't called. So this would not be an option at the moment.**